# Cisco ASA to Watchguard

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa, watchguard

I have never worked with watchguard firebox firewalls in depth before and we are replacing a Cisco ASA 5515 with a Watchguard M390.  I am having a hard time interpreting the configuration settings in the cisco and where they would apply in the Watchguard. I was hoping someone would get me started.  For example for these cisco settings, how would i create them in the watchguard?  See  the cisco config examples below.  I have separated the various entries by numbering them and changed some names and x'd out some ip addresses.  There are 10 configurations I need to apply to the watchguard. There are many more but if I can see how to apply these 10, I can do the rest.  Thank you.

Cisco config examples:

1. object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_1 tcp
   port-object eq www
   port-object eq https
2. object-group service TCP_Allowed tcp
   description guest-network-portal-port
   port-object eq ftp
   port-object eq www
   port-object eq https
   port-object eq ssh
   port-object eq telnet
   port-object eq 1935
   port-object eq 2001
   port-object eq 2376
   port-object eq 465
   port-object eq 587
   port-object eq 7000
   port-object eq 993
   port-object eq 995
   port-object eq ftp-data
   port-object eq pop3
   port-object eq smtp
   port-object eq 5222
   port-object eq 8080
   port-object eq 2002
   port-object eq 123
3. access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_INBOUND extended permit tcp any host 10.10.xx.xx eq www
4. access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUTBOUND extended permit tcp 172.xx.xx.0 255.255.255.0 host 192.168.xx.xx object-group FileServerAccess
5. access-list Inside-SecPan_access_in extended permit icmp 20.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.0 172.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.252 object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_2
6. nat (inside,Outside) source static 10.xx.xx.xx 50.201.xx.xx-32 destination static ANY-IPV4 ANY-IPV4
7. nat (CONF,Outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
8. access-group guest_access_in in interface guest
9. aaa-server AAA (inside) host 10.xx.xx.xx
   ldap-base-dn dc=aaa,dc=local
   ldap-scope subtree
   ldap-naming-attribute sAMAccountname
   ldap-login-password xxxxxxxxxxxx
   ldap-login-dn cn=asaservice,cn=users,dc=adg,dc=local
   server-type microsoft
10. interface GigabitEthernet0/4.3
    vlan 3
    nameif AAA-SECURITY
    security-level 90
    ip address 20.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0):

Morning

Have been a huge Watchguard fan for years and have a multitude of their products at many sites, my suggestion to you would be to contact them for support to help you understand their product, just let them know you are trying to configure your first box, I am sure they will help you understand like they did me when I got my first one decades ago!

There are a lot unknowns above in your configuration file and what your goals actually are, best to talk with a pro at Watchguard.